# Error: Maximum recursion depth on using flask-babel method with Nereid

Tags: python, flask, tryton

I am getting maximum recursion depth error from [Nereid 3.2](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid).
I found main cause for this error is Babel [dateformat filter](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/blob/master/flask_babel/__init__.py#L322) in jinja template like

```
{{ blog_date | dateformat(format='MMM YY') }}
```

On debugging I found may be Nereid's [speaklater](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/blob/develop/nereid/templating.py#L34) for lazy rendering feature is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution and here is how I reach there.

Problem with recursion depth error with flask is its not easy to get root cause of problem, so with hit and trial approach I got tail of the problem.

Method call flow is like this:

dateformat filter > [format_date()](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/blob/62c290fba3c38a9974bad4398980c908b4600a59/flask_babel/__init__.py#L322) > [to_user_timezone()](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/blob/62c290fba3c38a9974bad4398980c908b4600a59/flask_babel/__init__.py#L339) > [get_timezone()](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/blob/62c290fba3c38a9974bad4398980c908b4600a59/flask_babel/__init__.py#L289)

Now get timezone method is overridden [here](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/blob/2c1d17066a97a6b5f21d124d8a3aebd0c7fc4592/nereid/contrib/locale.py#L146-L173) as:

```
def get_timezone():
    """
    Returns the timezone that should be used for this request as
    `pytz.timezone` object.  This returns `None` if used outside of
    a request.
    """
    ctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
    tzinfo = getattr(ctx, 'babel_tzinfo', None)
    if tzinfo is None:
    babel = ctx.app.extensions['babel']
    if babel.timezone_selector_func is None:
        if not current_user.is_anonymous() and current_user.timezone:
        tzinfo = timezone(current_user.timezone)
        else:
        tzinfo = timezone(ctx.request.nereid_website.timezone)
    else:
        rv = babel.timezone_selector_func()
        if rv is None:
        tzinfo = babel.default_timezone
        else:
        if isinstance(rv, basestring):
            tzinfo = timezone(rv)
        else:
            tzinfo = rv
    ctx.babel_tzinfo = tzinfo
    return tzinfo

flask.ext.babel.get_timezone = get_timezone
```

From [here](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/blob/2c1d17066a97a6b5f21d124d8a3aebd0c7fc4592/nereid/contrib/locale.py#L160) it is calling a [function field timezone](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/blob/2c1d17066a97a6b5f21d124d8a3aebd0c7fc4592/trytond_nereid/website.py#L98) in nereid_website, which by default returning company's [timezone](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/blob/2c1d17066a97a6b5f21d124d8a3aebd0c7fc4592/trytond_nereid/website.py#L109), a field which is not required.

Finally, I have fixed this issue in [PR#229](https://github.com/openlabs/nereid/pull/229). Welcome reviewers!